# PHP Trim www if exists and remove path

Tags: php

I have an array of domain names, like:

```
array(
'http://example.co.uk/foo/bar',
'http://www.example.com/foo/bar',
'http://example.net/foo/bar')
```

And so on.

I am using

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

to trim everything and just keep the domain name and it's working partly however, it's keeping the www part if it exists.
How can I remove the 'www' if it exists. I tried to explicitly remove it from the domain name in the array, but when it resolves it reverts back to www.example.com.

So I'd like to return:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar > example
www.example.co.uk/foo/bar > example
example.com/foo/bar > example
example.net/foo/bar > example
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function below is not a general purpose function to get the domain name or domain part of a FQDN.  Rather it will return the first label (from left to right) if it is not www, and the second label if it is.  As requested above.

```
<?php

function get_domain_from_host($host)
{
    $parts = explode('.', $host);
    $domain = strpos($host, 'www') === 0
        ? next($parts)
        : current($parts);

    return $domain;
}

function test()
{
    $urls_wanted = array(
        'http://www.example.com/foo/bar' => 'example',
        'http://www.example.co.uk/foo/bar' => 'example',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar' => 'example',
        'http://example.net/foo/bar' => 'example'
    );

    foreach($urls_wanted as $url => $wanted) {
        $host   = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $domain = get_domain_from_host($host);
        print assert($wanted == $domain);
    }
}

test(); // Outputs: 1111
```

Example use (copy the function above):

```
$url    = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar';
$host   = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain = get_domain_from_host($host);
echo $domain; // output is 'example'.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I use this? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @AbuNooh did you try the code?  I've added an example use.

Comment: This is not very resistant to attempts to subvert. The fqdn should be extracted using parse_URL first.

Comment: @symcbean, I have included parse_url() as the OP did.  Did you read the question?

Comment: Whoops, sorry Progrock's.

Comment: My original function was badly named, updated, hopefully will be clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

You can match using the regex `~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^\./]+)~i`.

**Limitations**:

Please note that it will parse the *valid domain* `www.com` incorrectly and return `com` rather than `www`. It will only parse them incorrectly if the name part is `www` (`www.net`, `www.co.uk` etc.).

**Autopsy**:

- `~` *we specify our modifier character - the regex will know that the next time it sees this character all we specify is the modifiers*
- `(?:https?://)?` *an optional non-capturing group:*

  - `?:` *means that it's a non-capturing group (without it we'd have to use `return $match[3]`)*
  - `http` *the literal string `http`*
  - `s?` *the character `s` matched 0 to 1 time (it's optional)*
  - `://` *the literal string `://`*
  - `(..)?` *the entire group matched 0 to 1 time (optional)*
- `(?:www\.)?` *an optional non-capturing group:*

  - `?:` *means that it's a non-capturing group (without it we'd have to use `return $match[3]`)*
  - `www\.` *the literal string `www.` - we need to escape the dot with a slash, as the dot has special meaning in regex (any character)*
  - `(..)?` *the entire group matched 0 to 1 time (optional)*
- `([^\./]+)` *a capturing group:*

  - `[^\./]+` *any character that ISN'T `.` or `/` matched 1 to infinity times*
- `~i` - *our ending modifier character - `i` means that the entire regex is incasesensitive (so we match `HTTPS` and `WwW`)

[**Debuggex**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/D_UbyZ4E-_zs6dWu):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Function**:

```
<?php

function getSiteName($url) {
    if (preg_match('~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([^\./]+)~i', $url, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    }

    throw new \Exception(sprintf('Could not match URL "%s"', $url));
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$siteName = getSiteName('http://www.example.com/foo/bar');
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/489429):

```
var_dump( getSiteName( 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar' ) );
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'https://example.co.uk/foo/bar' ) ); 
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'www.example.com/foo/bar' ) );  
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'www.example.co.uk/foo/bar' ) );  
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'example.com/foo/bar' ) );  
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'example.net/foo/bar' ) );  
// string(7) "example"

var_dump( getSiteName( 'www.com/foo/bar' ) );  
// string(3) "com" (fails)
```

Comment: Like Progrock's answer this will work for the test cases but does not correctly parse the URL.

Comment: @symcbean Which URL wouldn't it be able to parse except for domains named `www`?

Comment: Http://www:randomtext@www.notremoved.com/path (for example)

Comment: Fair enough, with the exception of domains with user and passwords in them. All it would take would be another optional capturing group before www: `(?:[^:]+:[^:]+@)?`.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent verbose answer, it works as expected as does progrock's. In this case I'd never use an unconventional url such as one with the username passed in it.

Comment: @AbuNooh You're welcome. Hopefully you learnt something. :-) Consider changing `strpos` to [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) in progrocks answer so you won't run into issues with capital urls (eg. `WWW.EXAMPLE.COM`).

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes will change and definitely learnt something new. Your one is equally the right answer, though I think regex uses up more resources hence choosing other answer. Once again thank you for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to strip the 'www' than you could use str_replace for strpos for checking if 'www' in your string.

```
$url = "";
if (strpos($url,'www') !== false) {
    $url = str_replace("www", "", $url);
}
```

Edit: to strip almost all of your url (including domain extension and www (if exists)) you could do:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=\.[^.]+$)/', "example.com/foo/bar")[0];
if (strpos($result,'www') !== false) {
    $result = str_replace("www.", "", $result);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what about the path? example.com/foo/bar

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helped :)

Comment: It's still wrong. Should be `$result=strtolower($result); if (0===strpos($result,'www.')) { $result=preg_replace('/^www\./','',$result); }` (although the conditional is somewhat redundant)